# Crystal printing blank page at the end of the report when subreport is in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report containing 2 subreports. The whole thing easily fits on one page but a second blank page is consistently being generated.

This has nothing to do with the page width being too large because it
isn't, and the second blank page displays the report header and footer.
i have supressed the unused section even after that second blank page is diaplayed with  report header and footer.

Comment: when the blank page prints out, are you displaying the subreports?

Comment: also try setting Adjust Automatically in Report Properties  -> Page Layout screen